# How to initialize log4j2 in Spring Java configuration based app during Unit Tests?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, log4j2

I'm using Spring Framework (4.1.0) to build sample application where I can play with Unit Tests.

My test class use `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` annotation which logs **WARNS**

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner).
>
> log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

in console because I'm not using `log4j2` file based configuration.

My test class also use `@ContextConfiguration(classes = { AppConfig.class, ServletConfig.class })` annotation to point to context where I try to initialize log4j2.

**Question**: How can I properly initialize log4j2 to use it with `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`  without file based configuration ?

Other Java based config approaches are welcome :)

Comment: I place a log4j.xml file in my test/resources folder.

Comment: And for the record the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` has nothing to do with log4j.

Comment: @Hannes, correct me if I'm wrong but in source of `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` at the beginning we have `private static final org.apache.commons.logging.Log logger;` which means it's related with `log4j2`.

Comment: That's the commons-logging and will look up the logging mechanism you use. So if it finds a log4 lib, it will use this. If nothing is found it will use sysout.

Comment: You're right, but the question is still valid then.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize Log4j2 programmatically. There is an example [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html) on the Log4j2 website under the section *'Programatically Adding to the Current Configuration'* showing how to add an appender.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following file content as `log4j.xml` to your classpath root:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true" xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'> 
   <appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1} - %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>
   <root>
      <level value="INFO"/>
      <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
   </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

This should configure log4j. However, check you lib path. There must be a log4j jar anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You may have both `log4j` and `log4j2` jars on your classpath.

So `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` is trying to use `log4j` instead of `log4j2`. Remove the `log4j` jar and use `log4j-1.2-api` instead.

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#which_jars